# Upload template.pnp to SPO site collection and having it as template option when creating new site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have the testtemplate.xml and testtemplate.pnp files ready for a new template that I would like to deploy in my site collection. How can I achieve this in a way that when I want to create a new site testtemplate will be an option?

Comment: Are you looking for custom site templates? This new feature might help you: [Site templates are coming to SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/11/site-templates-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: It's similar. I created a site and want to turn it into a template that can be reused when creating a new site. Site designs won't save the webpart layout in home.aspx